# What is the probability for each of these three side-gigs that you would work at least 40 hours a month during summer months (June, July, and August)

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MRqrG.jpg)Eric (washes cars and such):
Jan Feb Mar Apr May June    July    Aug Sept    Oct Nov Dec
18  22  24  30  35  30  35  37  32  26  28  30

Ariel (sells homemade popsicles)
Jan Feb Mar Apr May June    July    Aug Sept    Oct Nov Dec
16  16  32  32  28  34  40  30  28  20  22  24

Sebastian (landscaping)
Jan Feb Mar Apr May June    July    Aug Sept    Oct Nov Dec
12  16  20  25  32  40  40  40  35  31  24  20

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Suppose that during a specific 3 month period, person x works A hours in the 1st month, B hours in the 2nd month, and C hours in the 3rd month.  Suppose further that you are asked, whether this person works at least n hours a month during each of these months.  The answer to that will be either **Yes** or **No**.  Suppose that you have $R$ people, and among these $R$ people, you accumulate $k$ **Yes** answers and $(R-k)$ **No** answers.  Then what are the chances that a randomly selected person from among the $R$ people will have been assigned a **Yes** answer?

Comment: You have friends that have experience with these weekend “side-gig” businesses already (they inspired you!).  Three friends graciously provided you with the following info on the amount of monthly time spent (in hours) on their business (assume all three businesses have comparable annual revenues and profit margins):

Comment: I'm confused.  What does your comment have to do with my comment?  My comment was intended to suggest a way of interpreting the information so that you could solve the problem mathematically.